# Php Debug on Zend Eclipse - File doesn't exist

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging

Screen shot here
**https://i.stack.imgur.com/I70Yq.png**

When I tried to browse the target file, it stated that "No entries available" and The Debug button is always disable.

What's the problem with this?

Comment: Am having the same problem with Eclipse Juno.